# Spring Boot Validation BindingResult always contains no errors

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, spring-security

I`m creating my spring boot application. In my class User there are a lot of validation annotations. Also, i`m hadling validation issues in my controller using bindingResult.hasErrors().
The problem is that my binding result is always has no errors.

Here is my controller and User class:

```
@PostMapping("/registration")
    public String registerUser(Model model, @Valid User user, @ModelAttribute("confirmPassword") String confirmPassword, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("allProjects", projectService.getAllProjects());
            return "registration";
        }

        User existingUser = userService.findByLogin(user.getLogin());
        if (existingUser != null) {
            model.addAttribute("userExistsError", true);
            model.addAttribute("allProjects", projectService.getAllProjects());
            return "registration";
        }

        if (!user.getPassword().equals(confirmPassword)) {
            model.addAttribute("passwordMismatch", true);
            model.addAttribute("allProjects", projectService.getAllProjects());
            return "registration";
        }

        userService.saveUser(user);
        return "redirect:/home";
    }
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Login cannot be blank!")
    @Email(message = "Invalid email format")
    @Column(name = "login", length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String login;

    @NotBlank(message = "Password cannot be blank!")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=\\S+$).{8,}$",
            message = "Password must be at least 8 characters long, contain at least one digit, one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter, and one special character")
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "created_at", updatable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    private java.sql.Timestamp createdAt;

    @Column(name = "roles", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String roles;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    private Project project;
}
```

I`ve tried changing versions of validators and debugging my app, but nothing helped.

Comment: what kind of dependencies are you including?  take a look at `spring-boot-starter-validation` if it's missing maybe that could have the issue.

Comment: if it's not a dependency issue, take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69692047/3693843 it might shed some light.

Comment: Here are my dependencies:
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>